# android : merge two videos

Tags: java, android, video

I want to merge two videos in android i am following this link https://code.google.com/p/mp4parser/ but it is not working for me so please help me thanks here is my code and log cat errors:-

code is :

MovieCreator mc = new MovieCreator();

```
    try {
        Movie  video = mc.build(Channels.newChannel(MainActivity.class.getResourceAsStream("/video.mp4")));

    Movie audio = mc.build(Channels.newChannel(MainActivity.class.getResourceAsStream("/funnysardar.mp4")));


    List<Track> videoTracks = video.getTracks();
    video.setTracks(new LinkedList<Track>());

    List<Track> audioTracks = audio.getTracks();


    for (Track videoTrack : videoTracks) {
       video.addTrack(new AppendTrack(videoTrack, videoTrack));
    }
    for (Track audioTrack : audioTracks) {
       video.addTrack(new AppendTrack(audioTrack, audioTrack));
    }

    IsoFile out = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(video);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(String.format("output.mp4")));
    out.getBox(fos.getChannel());
    fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

log cat error is :-

```
07-29 07:29:08.120: E/AndroidRuntime(6456): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-29 07:29:08.120: E/AndroidRuntime(6456): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.merge/com.example.merge.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-29 07:29:08.120: E/AndroidRuntime(6456):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
07-29 07:29:08.120: E/AndroidRuntime(6456):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
07-29 07:29:08.120: E/AndroidRuntime(6456):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-29 07:29:08.120: E/AndroidRuntime(6456):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
07-29 07:29:08.120: E/AndroidRuntime(6456):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-29 07:29:08.120: E/AndroidRuntime(6456):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-29 07:29:08.120: E/AndroidRuntime(6456):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-29 07:29:08.120: E/AndroidRuntime(6456):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-29 07:29:08.120: E/AndroidRuntime(6456):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-29 07:29:08.120: E/AndroidRuntime(6456):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-29 07:29:08.120: E/AndroidRuntime(6456):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-29 07:29:08.120: E/AndroidRuntime(6456):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-29 07:29:08.120: E/AndroidRuntime(6456): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-29 07:29:08.120: E/AndroidRuntime(6456):     at java.nio.channels.Channels$ReadableByteChannelImpl.read(Channels.java:350)
07-29 07:29:08.120: E/AndroidRuntime(6456):     at com.coremedia.iso.AbstractBoxParser.parseBox(AbstractBoxParser.java:55)
07-29 07:29:08.120: E/AndroidRuntime(6456):     at com.coremedia.iso.IsoFile.next(IsoFile.java:162)
07-29 07:29:08.120: E/AndroidRuntime(6456):     at com.coremedia.iso.IsoFile.hasNext(IsoFile.java:138)
07-29 07:29:08.120: E/AndroidRuntime(6456):     at com.googlecode.mp4parser.util.LazyList$1.hasNext(LazyList.java:55)
07-29 07:29:08.120: E/AndroidRuntime(6456):     at com.coremedia.iso.IsoFile.getMovieBox(IsoFile.java:241)
07-29 07:29:08.120: E/AndroidRuntime(6456):     at com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.container.mp4.MovieCreator.build(MovieCreator.java:57)
07-29 07:29:08.120: E/AndroidRuntime(6456):     at com.example.merge.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
07-29 07:29:08.120: E/AndroidRuntime(6456):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-29 07:29:08.120: E/AndroidRuntime(6456):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
com.coremedia.iso.PropertyBoxParserImpl;

InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/isoparser-default.properties");
```

In Android projects, this: `inputStream = null;`

Comment: @DiegoStiehl, Why are you putting this comments to me.. Are you awake from sleep..

Comment: @bgs Sorry. You're completely right about being awake from sleep. I mistook the browser tabs. =/