# AOSP L build - screenrecord - CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE

Tags: android, build, android-source

I needed screenrecord application in android L to record longer videos.
I followed advice from this question and decided to build android.
[How to increase time limit of ADB screen record of Android Kitkat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21938948/how-to-increase-time-limit-of-adb-screen-record-of-android-kitkat)

After many attempts I haven't succeded, because screenrecorder binary extracted from build doesn't work. 
When I push screenrecord file to ANDROID and after chmod and starting screenrecord this is communicate I'm getting:

```
CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE: empty/missing DT_HASH in "./screenrecord" (built with --hash-style=gnu?)
```

I am using Ubuntu 14 and lunch configuration hammerhead as I am testing this on Nexus 5.

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 5):

One option is to add "LOCAL_LDFLAGS := -Wl,--hash-style=sysv" at screenrecord Android.mk though I am sure there is a less hacky method of doing so..

Comment: Adding "LOCAL_LDFLAGS := -Wl" leads to compilation error: Wl: No such file or directory
Adding just "--hash-style = gnu" / "--hash-style = sysv" into Android.mk, compilation goes fine but the error still persists when run the application (built with --hash-style=gnu?)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the limit for Android L, but 180 seconds is the max limit for KitKat, I run multi time ( 3min each) and combine it together.

see this thread:
[android : merge two videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17919744/android-merge-two-videos)